# Physics - Projectile get launch angle to hit desired location?

Tags: physics, projectile

I am programming a simple ball projectile in a game.
the update pretty much looks like:

```
velocity += gravity;
velocity *=0.9;
pos += vel;
```

Is there a way to set the angle and power of the launch in order to hit a point that is specified with the mouse?
like peggle, http://youtu.be/4KbNiWsgJck?t=45s

I know there is a solution that I have used several years ago, but I can't find it.
I believed it turned my update into a quadratic formula, or derived it or something.
It had two solutions that was solved with the quadratic equation.

ps- hopefully this could be in 3D, but I could use a 2D solution too because my curve would be 2D

any help?
thanks,
Dan

Comment: In that video it looks as if the user controls angle, but not power (at least at first-- I'm not going to sit through the whole thing). Is that what you want?

Comment: There is no single solution to both velocity and angle but rather a whole family of parametric solutions of the velocity as a function of the angle or vice versa. As for the 2D vs 3D, the actual trajectory is really 2D - it lies completely in a vertical plane (unless there is side wind blowing or other side force).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this.  If you can change the angle and speed, you have more variability than you need, so you have to find a reasonable set of parameters that will work, which isn't hard.  The basic equations are:

x = x<sub>0</sub> + t*v<sub>0x</sub> 
y = y<sub>0</sub> + v<sub>0y</sub>t + (1/2)a<sub>y</sub>t<sup>2</sup>

Here, x and y will be the points you want to hit, and t will be the time that you hit them.  *t* won't show up in the final solution, but you'll use it as in intermediary to calculate the values you want.

Basically, then, pick a reasonable value for v<sub>0x</sub>.  Using the x-equation, find what *t* will be when the target is hit.  Then plug this value into the y-equation, and solve for v<sub>0y</sub>.  This then will give you a pair of values of v<sub>0x</sub> and v<sub>0y</sub> that will work to hit the target.